# Partial derivative and limit

Tags: partial-derivative

The function $ f(x,y)=0$   $if$  $x,y≠0$ $and$ $ f(x,y)=1$ $if$ $ x,y=0$ is given. I have to prove that partial derivative of $x$ and partial derivative of $y$ exist at the beginning of the axes and find them.I am confused about how we find the derivatives.

Comment: The specification of $f(x,y)$ is unclear. Do the commas in “$x,y$” mean **and** or **or**?

Comment: I meant x AND y ,the function consists of two variables

Comment: If it's **and** in both cases, then you haven't specified $f(x,y)$ for all $(x,y)$. You need **and** in one case and **or** in the other!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Partial derivatives exist for any $ (a,b)\neq(0,0)$, let proceed by the definition

$$f_x=\lim_{h\to0}\frac{f(a+h,b)-f(a,b)}{h}$$

$$f_x=\lim_{h\to0}\frac{f(a,b+h)-f(a,b)}{h}$$